# How to add an array to a list by value not by reference?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, pass-by-value

Is there a way to add an array to a list of arrays by value and not by reference?

Example: The following prints out "6, 7, 8, 9, 10". I want it to write out "1, 2, 3, 4, 5".

```
int[] testArray = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int[]> testList = new List<int[]>();

testList.Add(testArray);

testArray[0] = 6;
testArray[1] = 7;
testArray[2] = 8;
testArray[3] = 9;
testArray[4] = 10;

foreach(int[] array in testList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4]);
}
```

Comment: You need to create a copy of the array.

Comment: Everything *is* added to a list by value. Your confusion arises from the fact that arrays, like all objects, are not values in C#. `testArray` is not an object -- it is a *reference* (pointer to an object).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a copy:

```
testList.Add(testArray.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `Clone()` the array i.e. **create shallow copy of array** and add that in the list.

```
testList.Add((int[])testArray.Clone());
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
testList.Add(testArray);
```

use

```
testList.Add(testArray.Clone() as int[]);
```

Comment: `Clone()` returns object so you have to type cast it back to array.